# Angular Material and Custom theming

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, styling

Angular material styling is loaded last and overriding my custom theming css. My custom css should load at end of all the base material css.

Answer (score 0):

A way for overriding css you can use `/deep/` selector with class or id

```
/deep/ materialClass.yourClass {
  // Your CSS
}
```